# Problema con str.contains()

Tags: python, string, pandas

En estas 2 variables:

```
fecha = str(salco_concat['FECHA'].max())
ayer = str(salco_concat['FECHA'].max()- datetime.timedelta(days=1))
```

tengo la fecha más actual de una base, junto a su día anterior.

Ahora bien, me gustaría poder filtrar las columnas de la imagen considerando las variables `fecha` o `ayer`, o sea que **filtre las columnas que cumplan con `fecha` y las columnas que cumplan con `ayer`)**, pero no se me ocurre como hacerlo.

[image: Imagen de las columnas que necesito filtrar]

Lo intenté hacer con

```
ps.loc[:, ps.columns.str.contains((fecha|ayer),case=False, regex=True)]
```

pero me sale este error

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'

---

Tengo la última duda....

ahumada_concat[ahumada_concat.columns[pd.Series(ahumada_concat.columns).str.contains(f'{fecha}|{ayer}']]

Cuando hago ese código, me arroja solamente los números de filas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo podría solucionar eso??

Muchas gracias y perdón por no editar el código, no me deja usar espacios

Comment: para unir strs usas `fecha + ayer`, no `fecha | ayer`

Comment: lo puse asi ahora, y me salieron 426 filas pero 0 columnas.

Comment: Supongo que lo quieres hacer es `ps.columns.str.in([fecha, ayer], case=False)` (no entiendo el por qué de `regex=True`, además)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que debes pasar una cadena, aun con `regex=True`, el [argumento `pat` siempre espera una cadena](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html). Para formar la cadena puedes usar formateo de cadenas simplemente:

```
ps.loc[:, ps.columns.str.contains(f"{hoy}|{ayer}", regex=True)]
```

Por ejemplo:

```
import re
import pandas as pd


hoy = "foo"
ayer = "bar"

df = pd.DataFrame({"foo_a": (1, 2),
                   "faa_a": (2, 3),
                   "bar_a": (3, 4),
                   "go_foo": (4, 5),
                   "baar_b": (5, 6)}
                  )
fil = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains(f"{hoy}|{ayer}", regex=True)]
```

> ```
> >>> fill
>
>    foo_a  bar_a  go_foo
> 0      1      3       4
> 1      2      4       5
> ```

Comment: Me acaba de funcionar inmediatamente con lo que comentaste
Muchas gracias!!!